# Fourier transformation of summation of bosonic operators with alternate signs.

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-transform

The sum of the following Bosonic operators: $$ \sum_{<ij>}a_{i}^{+}a_{j}+a_{j}^{+ }a_{i} $$ where i is the lattice site index(i=1 to N, it has periodic boundary condition, $$ r_{i+N}=r_{i}$$, j: nearest neighbour, and it can be rewritten as:  $$ (1/2) \times \sum_{i,i+\delta}a_{i}^{+}a_{i+\delta}+a_{i+\delta}^{+}a_{i} $$ The Fourier Transformation is defined as $$ a_{i}^{+}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{k}e^{-i.\vec k. \vec r_{i}}a_{k}^{+}\\ a_{i}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{k}e^{i.\vec k. \vec r_{i}}a_{k} $$ The rest of the calculation is straightforward and it gives us $$ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\delta,k}(e^{i.\vec k.\vec \delta} + e^{-i.\vec k.\vec \delta})a_{k}^{+}a_{k} $$ The question is, How to perform the Fourier transformation of the series: $$  \sum_{<ij>}(-1)^{(i+1)} (a_{i}^{+}a_{j}+a_{j}^{+}a_{i})$$ and what will be the answer? I am getting 0. Also, any kind of reference to related mathematical texts will be appreciated. Regards.

Comment: The title is not too informative. The Hamiltonian you are referring to is a tight binding model with alternating signs. I'm surprised it's a bosonic model as usually these are models of solids and the hopping particles are somehow electrons. Your question may be better suited for physics SE. Coming to the one particle problem itself it can be solved by defining a cell with two sites. Translation invariance by two sites is preserved and this induces a certain Fourier transform. In any case looking for tight binding model with alternating hopping should give you plenty of results.

Comment: That might work. I'll look into it. Thank You. @Icv